# Symfony time field not using the same date as the corresponding entity property

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've got an entity with a `duration` property, declared as [`time`](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#time) type:

```
/* @ORM\Column(type="time") */
private $duration;
```

In my Symfony form, this duration property maps to a [`time`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/time.html) field:

```
$builder->add(
    'duration',
    'time',
    [
        'input'  => 'datetime',
        'widget' => 'text'
    ]
)
```

As the `time` type does not exist in PHP, both internally use a `DateTime` object, so they need to add (invent) a date.

My problem is they don't appear to use the same date:

- 15mn extracted from the database are treated as `1970-01-01 00:15:00`
- 15mn submitted by the form are treated as `2015-06-06 00:15:00` (i.e. today's date)

Consequence: Doctrine always consider the time has changed and always performs an SQL update.

What is the most efficient way to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution lies in the `setDuration()` setter, as both Doctrine and Symfony use it to set the duration. Just don't update the whole `DateTime` object, only its time part:

```
public function setDuration(\DateTime $duration)
{
    $this->duration->setTime(
        $duration->format('G'),
        $duration->format('i'),
        $duration->format('s')
    );

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you could set the datetime to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 in the constructor of your entity

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->duration = new \DateTime('1970-01-01 00:00:00');
}
```